# Could someone help me to say why I get this error because the main.exe does not exist?

Tags: c

I have followed all the indications of how to configure SLD2 to the letter but even so it still has the same error
I have a problem with sdl2 library when I execute the main.cpp file it sends me this message.enter image description here

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Instead of linking to an image, please type your code into your post.

Comment: Have you followed [Setting up SDL on Windows](https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/index.php) -- can't beat Lazy foo... It's clear your compiler cannot find the definition for `SDL_Init()` and `SDL_CreateWindows()`, etc..

Comment: but I am using vscode and in the documentation that option does not appear, eh reviewing its documentation but I have a lot of doubts

Answer (score 3):

Your compiler is sending the binary to `hellocpp/src/main.exe` instead of `hellocpp/main.exe`. You'll need to edit your launch script or build configuration to fix this.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. It's not creating the exe because of the undefined references during linking.

Comment: Maybe, but it's still a problem he'll have to solve eventually

Comment: But maybe it's also the problem, because of `-o .../src/main.exe`

Comment: I just followed your instructions, but it gives the same result, but command the capture of what could be the problem.

Comment: @CarlosAlfredoAlvarezlopez you really have two problems here. Your code is not compiling because you don't link the SDL library (which you can do with the `-lSDL` library on `gcc`, I'm not sure about MSVC) **and** you're saving the binary to a different location. You'll need to at least fix both

Comment: well that explains why it is not compiled as such that is why these messages appear:
undefined reference to `SDL_Quit '
c: / mingw / bin /../ lib / gcc / mingw32 / 6.3.0 /../../../ libmingw32.a (main.o) :(. text.startup + 0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain @ 16 '

Comment: so this linked files in the json task.json doesn't work at all:

"-IC: /SDL2/SDL2-devel-2.0.14-mingw/SDL2-2.0.14/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include",
"-LC: /SDL2/SDL2-devel-2.0.14-mingw/SDL2-2.0.14/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib",

Comment: So I'm not sure if this is the issue, but I don't know if GCC does automatic path conversion. Try surrounding those blocks in single quotes and use the \ separator instead of `/`. For example: `g++ '-LC:\Your\Path\Here'`